# Using sqlitegen plugin in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, plugins

I am trying to install sqlitegen(http://code.google.com/p/sqlitegen/) plugin for my android development. I downloaded the plugin(http://code.google.com/p/sqlitegen/downloads/detail?name=sqlitegen_eclipse_site_0.1.18.jar&can=2&q=) and put it in plugins folder under Eclipse. Eclipse is not able to load the plugin.

Is there any additional dependencies or changes that I need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you read and have done this? It sounds you have only one of them

> You will need to download 2 files to use the plugin.
>
> sqlitegen_eclipse_site_xxx.jar is a file containing an Eclipse plugin
>   installation site in jar form. Download this file and configure it as
>   a feature download site in the Eclipse software update panel; then you
>   can install the plugin from it.
>
> com.antlersoft.android.db_xxx.jar is a library jar with the
>   dependencies required by the code generated by the plugin. Add this
>   file as a library to the build path of any Eclipse project that will
>   use the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

if you wondered like me on how to
 "configure a jar file as a feature download site in the Eclipse software update panel"

it is step 5 in this documentation
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-127.htm