# how to configure jar file as a feature download site in the Eclipse software update panel

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to install sqlitegen

i think my question is the same as in [Using sqlitegen plugin in Eclipse for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436674/using-sqlitegen-plugin-in-eclipse-for-android)
but the thing that i don't know how to do it is 
"configure it as a feature download site in the Eclipse software update panel"
 how to configure jar file as a feature download site in the Eclipse software update panel?
 i am very new in eclipse i am using adt and i need a little more detailed answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it .

it is step 5 in this documentation
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-127.htm

Add a new site using the  Install/Update > Available Software Sites preference page.

- Click the Add... button.
- If the software site is in your local file system but is packaged as a jar or zip file, 
  click   Archive... to specify the name of the file.